# Filter Nested Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This code snippet works to just filter array of objects using a string value.

So how can I make the code snippet cater for a nested object, so that it can filter both array of objects as well as a nested object within?

```js
mainLogic = (_data, search) => {
   //_data is an array of objects
    let _allsearch = search.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (_allsearch.length > 0) {
      _data = Object.values(_data).filter((obj) => {
        return Object.keys(obj).some((key) => {
       // the code usually breaks at this point. when it encounters a nested object
            return obj[key].toLowerCase().includes(_allsearch); 
        });
      });
    }
    return _data;

  };
```

This is a sample object:

```
let _data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    firstname: "Precious",
    lastname: "Same",
    age: "29",
    state: "Abia",
    email: "sam@gmail.com",
    country: "Michigan",
    town:{
      name:"Jos"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    firstname: "Bolu",
    lastname: "Joke",
    age: "32",
    state: "Ogun",
    email: "bolu.joke@outlook.com",
    country: "america",
    town:{
      name:"California"
    }
  }
]
```

When calling the function:

```js
this.mainLogic(_data, "california")
```

This is what I expect:

```
[
  {
    id: "2",
    firstname: "Bolu",
    lastname: "Joke",
    age: "32",
    state: "Ogun",
    email: "bolu.joke@outlook.com",
    country: "america",
    town:{
      name:"Califonia"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it clearer, I have no idea what you actually want, or what you are having trouble with.

Comment: please add some data and the wanted result by calling the function.

Comment: In general is also good to additionally indicate what your code does, and how it *differs* from what you want. Or briefly spell out what you think your code is doing, or specifically what piece or concept you're having difficulty with. This  can help an experienced developers to quickly hone in on your issue, efficiently - sometimes without having to first work out all the code as written, we can quickly recognize patterns and immediately know exactly which line of code to focus on.

Comment: "code breaks here". Please indicate specifically how it breaks. Is there an error message. Does it gives different results than you expect? If so, how so? Good improvement, please add even more details, or clarify the question again. Also look up MVP in the help section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to flat object, then array could be easily filtered:

```
_data.forEach((el, i) => {
  let flattenedObject = flatObject(el);
  if (Object.values(flattenedObject).includes(searchWord))
    _data = _data.filter((f, ind) => ind == i);
})
```

An example:

```js
let _data = [
      {
        id: "1",
        firstname: "Precious",
        lastname: "Same",
        age: "29",
        state: "Abia",
        email: "sam@gmail.com",
        country: "Michigan",
        town:{
          name:"Jos"
        }
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        firstname: "Bolu",
        lastname: "Joke",
        age: "32",
        state: "Ogun",
        email: "bolu.joke@outlook.com",
        country: "america",
        town:{
          name:"California"
        }
      }
    ];


const flatObject = (obj) => {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    ...function _flatten(o) {
      return [].concat(...Object.keys(o)
        .map(k =>
          typeof o[k] === 'object' ?
            _flatten(o[k]) :
            ({[k]: o[k]})
        )
      );
    }(obj)
  )
}


let searchWord = 'California';

_data.forEach((el, i) => {
  let flattenedObject = flatObject(el);
  if (Object.values(flattenedObject).includes(searchWord))
    _data = _data.filter((f, ind) => ind == i);
})


console.log(_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Code mainly derived from [here](https://gist.github.com/penguinboy/762197)

I would just flatten the object, so that every property is on the same level and you do not need to cater for nested objects. After that, filtering is done the same way you are doing it now. (Left out verification and error checking, you can adapt your code)

```js
let data = [{
    id: "1",
    firstname: "Precious",
    lastname: "Same",
    age: "29",
    state: "Abia",
    email: "sam@gmail.com",
    country: "Michigan",
    town: {
      name: "Jos"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    firstname: "Bolu",
    lastname: "Joke",
    age: "32",
    state: "Ogun",
    email: "bolu.joke@outlook.com",
    country: "america",
    town: {
      name: "California"
    }
  }
];

function flattenObject(ob) {
  var toReturn = {};

  for (var i in ob) {
    if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;

    if ((typeof ob[i]) == 'object') {
      var flatObject = flattenObject(ob[i]);
      for (var x in flatObject) {
        if (!flatObject.hasOwnProperty(x)) continue;

        toReturn[i + '.' + x] = flatObject[x];
      }
    } else {
      toReturn[i] = ob[i];
    }
  }
  return toReturn;
};

function mainLogic(data, search) {
  for (let obj of data) {
    flattened = flattenObject(obj);
    if (Object.values(flattened).includes(search)) return obj;
  };
};

console.log(mainLogic(data, "California"))
```